# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: subSector.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm unable to map through json data from a fake api. It's working when returning more than one data but this error happens when the data is a single object.

Here is my code:

```js
    {subSector
     ? subSector.map((sector) => (
//               ^ ~ subSector.map is not a function
         <MenuItem value={sector.id}>{sector.email}</MenuItem>
       ))
    : "nodata"}
```

Comment: You could change your fake API to always give you arrays, or add another ternary to check if subSector is not an array and handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `map` on `subSector`, you are assuming it is an array of items and not a single item.

You are seeing the error because `subSector` is not an array, and therefore does not have the `map` function available.

Instead, either access the `subSector` properties directly (assuming `subSector` is a single item):

```
    {subSector ? (
         <MenuItem value={subSector.id}>{subSector.email}</MenuItem>
       )
    : "nodata"}
```

or handle both cases where it could be an array or single item:

```
    {Array.isArray(subSector)
     ? subSector.map((sector) => (
         <MenuItem value={sector.id}>{sector.email}</MenuItem>
       ))
    : subSector ? (
         <MenuItem value={subSector.id}>{subSector.email}</MenuItem>
       ) 
    : "nodata"}
```

or, as catgirlkelly says, ensure your fake data always returns an array, even for a single item.